# How do I align card image and card content next to one another? Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm having trouble creating a responsive card with the card image and content split into 2 different columns. One column containing the image and the other column containing the description.

I've tried using a row with two different columns, but I'm doing something wrong.

```
<v-layout column>
    <v-card dark flat>

      <v-row>

        <v-col cols="4">
            <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/store.jpg"></v-img>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="8">
            <v-card-title><h1>Title</h1></v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>Description</v-card-text>
        </v-col>

      </v-row>
    </v-card>
</v-layout>
```

The code above displays the image and the content in its own separate rows.
The card basically needs to have this format to it: https://uicookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/CSS-Cards-E-Commerce-Shop-Card.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a content aside image using v-list-item component

Working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/LYYjPKB?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      max-width="700"
      outlined
    >
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-avatar
          tile
          size="300"
          color="grey"
        ></v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <div class="overline mb-4">OVERLINE</div>
          <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1 pink--text">Women's Running Shoe</v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-title class="title mb-1">Nike epic react</v-list-item-title>
          <div>content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react v content for Nike epic react content for Nike epic react v content for Nike epic react</div>
        <v-btn text>Button</v-btn>
        </v-list-item-content>


      </v-list-item>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

})
```